# Full text search installed or not

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have instaled SQL server 2008 R2 and when I run this SQL in SQL server management studio:

```
SELECT FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')
```

I get 0

But If I run this:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.fulltext_catalogs
```

I get one row. I want to know If fulltext search is installed on my sql server or do I need to reinstall SQL server with advance options.

Please suggest.

Comment: Just tried this on my machine before Full Text Search was installed, `SELECT FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')` = 0, after = 1

Comment: I had the exact same problem, It was solved by running the database installer (SQLServer2017-SSEI-Dev.exe) in my case, and adding "FullText search..." feature.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

***My answer:***

If FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY says it's not installed, then I would install from the original media.  Run through the installer and simply add Full Text Search from the features page.

FTS is [fully in the SQL Engine in 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142541.aspx) so if it thinks it isn't installed, then ya best make it happy.

***My opinions/ponderings:***

Did you move a database from a previous SQL installation that had full text installed?  That might explain the row in sys.fulltext_catalogs.

When you open a Database in SSMS, under the Storage Folder, Full Text Catalog folder do you have the option to add a New Catalog when you right click?

In SQL Configuration Manager do you see the Full Text Daemon Launcher service?

[image]

Comment: I see the option to add new Full Text Catalog under storage. Also the current one is listed. I dont see the Full Text Daemon Launcher Service in SQL Configuration manager. Where can I find it. Is Full text search installed on my SQL server?

Comment: If the Daemon isn't there then it's not installed (at least fully).

Comment: I've updated my answer with a screen shot of what the Daemon looks like in SSCM

Answer (score 5):

### Easy way

```
SELECT 
CASE FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Full-Text installed.' 
    ELSE 'Full-Text is NOT installed.' 
END;
```

inspired by https://www.sqlshack.com/hands-full-text-search-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

I just made the test on a new SQL Server 2016 Express installation *without* fulltext feature (did not used the "Advanced Services" setup).

I can confirm you can perfectly create fulltext catalogs on databases even if fulltext feature is not intalled.

But if you try to create a fulltext index, you'll get a clear error message stating the feature is missing :

Executing :

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.tbltxt(coltext)  
   KEY INDEX ui_tbltxt   
   WITH STOPLIST = SYSTEM;  
GO
```

...will throws error :

> Msg 7609, Level 17, State 5, Line 87
>   Full-Text Search is not installed, or a full-text component cannot be loaded.