# How do I create a fulltext search index or catalog from a .NET application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, orchardcms

I am trying to deploy a full text search solution with SQL Server 2008 R2 and Orchard CMS with multi-tenancy configuration. Each tenant has its own database. We are using automatic data migrations to manage database schema changes. I would like to create a full text catalog and index using migrations. However I get following error:

`CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG statement cannot be used inside a user transaction.`

I do know the reason of the error but I cannot determine a workaround. I was trying to open a new database connection using `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` class inside the app and somehow configure it to not create transactions, however this did not achieve anything.

Is it possible to create a full text index/catalog through a .NET provider instead of directly connecting to database via SSMS?

EDIT:

I've tried with this code with SMO:

```
var server = new Server(new ServerConnection(new SqlConnection(connectionString)));

var database = server.Databases[databaseName];

var fulltextCatalog = new FullTextCatalog(database, fullTextCatalogName);
fulltextCatalog.Create();
```

It results with the same exception.

Comment: Can your database user execute other DDL operations without any error message?

Comment: Yes, the only two statements that do not work are `create fulltext catalog` and `create fulltext index`.

Comment: @Wojteq - What error shows up? Chances are you don't have Full Text Search installed. What version of SQL Server 2008 do you have installed? Run `SELECT FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')`, if you see `0` as the result, you don't have it installed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511167/full-text-search-installed-or-not

Comment: Fulltext search is installed. I'm using SQL Server R2.

Comment: @Wojteq - Can you post the error?

Comment: @Omar, I've already done it in the question.

Comment: It is very very strange that you would want to do that, as Orchard already has full-text search built-in.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy I know that there was Orchard.Indexing and Orchard.Lucene but may I use any of them to improve autocomplete search with hundreds of thousands rows underneath stored in SQL Server?

Comment: Yes. Lucene is a very mature indexing and searching solution. It's there. You should use it.

Answer (score 0):

User must have CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG permission on the database, or be a member of the db_owner, or db_ddladmin fixed database roles.

Comment: It's not an issue. The user is db_owner.

Comment: Did you enable Full Text search there. For example: Did you try?                    exec sp_fulltext_database 'enable'

Comment: Yes, it is enabled. I can do it with SSMS but not from application.

Comment: Again, I suspect the database user behind the application may not be member of either db_owner, or db_ddladmin.

Answer (score 0):

You can [create and manage full-text indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms219681%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) - and just about any other SQL Server object - using [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms212724%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. Could you look at my edited question?

Comment: You posted some code, and I assume that this comment means it didn't work, but you haven't explained why not: did you get an error, did nothing happen, did something unexpected happen...? I guess you're following the [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162152(v=sql.100).aspx) in the documentation?

Comment: I get this same error with following nested exceptions "An exception occurred while executing a "Create failed for FullTextCatalog 'Test_Catalog'." -> "Transact-SQL statement or batch" -> "CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG statement cannot be used inside a user transaction."

Comment: I found interesting issue. My posted code works inside separated console application but not inside the web application.