# How do I install SQL Full-text Search onto another instance?

Tags: sql-server

I have installed TFS onto another server, and restored the TFS databases to a new instance.

I keep running into the error: TF255149: The following server that is running SQL Server does not have the full-text search feature installed: [instance name]. This feature is required for Team Foundation Server to operate correctly.

I've been looking all over the Internet for a solution, and it turns out it's not installed after seeing [Full text search installed or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511167/full-text-search-installed-or-not).

I tried to re-run the ISO to add the feature but it's already selected BUT greyed out too. When I check the SQL Services Manager I see that there isn't a "SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher" for the instance but there is for the server itself, in comparison to the previous set-up I had where each instance had it's own.

Is there any way to install this onto the instance? Am I missing something?

I am running SQL Server 2016 Enterprise Edition SP1.

Comment: Did you select a right instance when re-ran ISO to add components?

Comment: Hi, turns out I was using the wrong ISO, (the SP1 upgrade ISO rather than the original installation ISO). When using the SP1 ISO I wasn't given the option to select an instance. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I answered my own question! I kept running the SP1 ISO rather than the original ISO, which allows me to add features to individual instances.